# htaccess redirect 301 from URL to URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have in my .htaccess file line like this, which is work:

```
Redirect 301 /redirect/test.php http://example_site/newtest/1-newtest
```

but I am wondering about that can I use this to redirect from URL to another URL like this:

```
Redirect 301 https://example_site.pl/test/test/1,test http://example_site.pl/newtest/1-newtest
```

or it can be redirected only from path to URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mod-rewrite` to redirect requests based on `HTTP_HOST` header . To redirect `/file.html` from `a.com` to `b.com` you can use something like the following:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?a\.com$
RewriteRule ^file\.html$ http://b.com/ [L,R]
```

References:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html